# Termination Description: DYLD, Symbol not found: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have such a problem, I put together a build for ios in unity.
When I run a app:

**-IOS 14+ and IOS 13.6 starts up and works**

**-IOS 12.3.1 and IOS 13.2 crashes when start**

The application opens, freezes and crashes.

```
Termination Description: DYLD, Symbol not found: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1C5FB058-3A1A-4845-A857-D4717591F4BA/ProductName.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework | Expected 

Thread 39 Crashed:
0   dyld                                  0x0000000100a0a398 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                                  0x0000000100a099d8 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2   dyld                                  0x0000000100a09a08 fcntl + 0
3   dyld                                  0x00000001009cc8f8 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 18680 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 0
4   dyld                                  0x00000001009cca14 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol+ 18964 (ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 284
5   libdyld.dylib                         0x00000001a8524848 dyld_stub_binder + 60
6   UnityFramework                        0x0000000107f0bf20 0x107000000 + 15777568
7   UnityFramework                        0x0000000107ee75d0 0x107000000 + 15627728
8   UnityFramework                        0x0000000107f07864 0x107000000 + 15759460
9   UnityFramework                        0x0000000107f074bc 0x107000000 + 15758524
10  UnityFramework                        0x0000000107ef03cc 0x107000000 + 15664076
11  UnityFramework                        0x0000000108109b30 0x107000000 + 17865520
12  UnityFramework                        0x0000000107f4d5ec 0x107000000 + 16045548
13  UnityFramework                        0x0000000107f4f2cc 0x107000000 + 16052940
14  UnityFramework                        0x0000000107f4f20c 0x107000000 + 16052748
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x00000001a86f02c0 _pthread_body + 128
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x00000001a86f0220 _pthread_start + 44
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x00000001a86f3cdc thread_start + 4
```

Know someone who can answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Those are system components. Generally, you should only go into those folders when you have a reason to do so.
2. When you run the second command, the change is being made to the root account's settings and not those for your normal account.